# node.js/express/mongoose combine async function loop in a async function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using Node.js and mongoose to fetch data.
Before sending the result i want to loop through the data and fetch some additional informations of a another mongoose collection.

I don't get it to manage, that the first mongoose call waits, that the other promises are finished.
I assume that my mixture of promises and .then calls is a mess... :S

My Code:

```
exports.checkChats = (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.userData.userId);
let modifiedChats = [];
let partner;
Messages.find({ $or: [{ "users.starter": req.userData.userId }, { "users.partner": req.userData.userId }] })
    .then(chats => {
        if (chats) {
            console.log('Start');
            const promises = chats.map(async chat => {
                if (chat.users.starter.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
                    console.log('fetch partnerData for partner ' + chat.users.partner);
                    partner = chat.users.partner;
                }
                if (chat.users.partner.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
                    console.log('fetch partnerData for starter ' + chat.users.starter);
                    partner = chat.users.starter;
                }
                User.findById(partner).then(fetchedPartner => {
                    console.log('Partner fetched: ', fetchedPartner.userName);
                    modifiedChats.push({ id: chat._id, status: chat.status, lastMessage: chat.lastMessage, partnerName: fetchedPartner.userName, partnerImg: fetchedPartner.imagePath });
                });
            });
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                console.log('End');
                res.status(201).json({
                    message: 'Chats found',
                    chats: modifiedChats
                });
            });
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Couldnt fetch chats!',
            error: error
        });
    });
};
```

And the Terminallog:

```
Start
fetch partnerData for partner 5eb8502aad51b72012a2ccd1
fetch partnerData for partner 5eb84c93ad51b72012a2cc56
End
Partner fetched:  Summer
Partner fetched:  Pepe
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so the problem in your code is located here

```
const promises = chats.map(async chat => {
  if (chat.users.starter.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
    console.log('fetch partnerData for partner ' + chat.users.partner);
    partner = chat.users.partner;
  }
  if (chat.users.partner.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
    console.log('fetch partnerData for starter ' + chat.users.starter);
    partner = chat.users.starter;
  }
  User.findById(partner).then(fetchedPartner => {
    console.log('Partner fetched: ', fetchedPartner.userName);
    modifiedChats.push({ id: chat._id, status: chat.status, lastMessage: chat.lastMessage, partnerName: fetchedPartner.userName, partnerImg: fetchedPartner.imagePath });
  });
});
```

Every iteration of this loop calls `User.findById(partner)` which returns a promise and is asynchronous. The function does not know that it needs to wait for its result.
One way to tell the function to wait for `User.findById(partner)` to finish is by adding `return`.

```
return User.findById(partner).then(fetchedPartner => {
    console.log('Partner fetched: ', fetchedPartner.userName);
    modifiedChats.push({ id: chat._id, status: chat.status, lastMessage: chat.lastMessage, partnerName: fetchedPartner.userName, partnerImg: fetchedPartner.imagePath });
  });
```

You can also remove the async in

```
const promises = chats.map(async chat => {
```

It serves no purpose, because you are not utilizing `async/await` anyway.

---

Here's also an example to refactor your code using `async/await`.

```
exports.checkChats = async (req, res, next) => { // by putting async here, you are enabling a function to use await
  try {
    console.log(req.userData.userId);
    let partner;
    const chats = await Messages.find({ $or: [{ "users.starter": req.userData.userId }, { "users.partner": req.userData.userId }] }); // by putting await before a function call the returns a promise, you will have the access to the value it will return by this syntax
    console.log('Start');
    const promises = chats.map(async chat => { // by putting async here, you are enabling a function to use await; This is also a function so you will need to put async here if you want to use await inside
      if (chat.users.starter.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
        console.log('fetch partnerData for partner ' + chat.users.partner);
        partner = chat.users.partner;
      }
      if (chat.users.partner.toString() === req.userData.userId.toString()) {
        console.log('fetch partnerData for starter ' + chat.users.starter);
        partner = chat.users.starter;
      }
      const fetchedPartner = await User.findById(partner); // same here, I put await because its a promise
      console.log('Partner fetched: ', fetchedPartner.userName);
      return { id: chat._id, status: chat.status, lastMessage: chat.lastMessage, partnerName: fetchedPartner.userName, partnerImg: fetchedPartner.imagePath }; // I am just returning the values here. By the end of the .map() it will have created an array of promises that each resolves the values return here
    });
    const modifiedChats = await Promise.all(promises); // this will convert the array of promises to an array of the values that was resolve  by each of the promises.
    console.log('End');
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Chats found',
      chats: modifiedChats
    });
  } catch (error) { // using try catch is the way for catching thrown errors / rejected promises
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Couldnt fetch chats!',
      error: error
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times - and also for your awesome explanations!